# Setting a value to private superclass-variables in a subclass without setters Java

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism

So i have this assignment in which i have a super class with a private intsance variable without a setter and that variable is not in the constructor parameters
and i need to assign a value to that variable using an overridden void type method in multiple subclasses with different values what should i do ?

Comment: example 
public class Car{
private int tyres;
private String name;
public Car(String name){
this.name="car";
}
getTyres{
return tyres;


public class Kia extends Car{

public void changeValue(){
What should i do??

Comment: Ask for a better assignment. It's not possible to change the private variable through regular means, if the superclass doesn't provide a setter for it.

Answer (score 0):

If u realy aren't allowed to use any setter methods and your variable has private access then u have to cheat the system with reflection api. Idk what programming language u are using but here is an sample of how u would do it in java

```
class Test<T> //Template cause u said it can have multiple values                              {
 private T secret;

 abstract void set(T myvalue);//this is void method u will be overriding
}

class A extends Test<Integer>
{
 void set(Integer value)
 {
  Field field=Test.class.getDeclaredField("secret");
  field.setAccessible(true);
  field.setValue(this,5);
 }
}

class B extends Test<Float>
{
 void set(Float value)
 {
  Fieldfield=Test.class.getDeclaredField("secret");
  field.setAccessible(true);
  field.setValue(this,5.5f);
 }
}
```

As u can see we have no access to variable secret in class T from our sub classes but we if we just know it's name we can hack in to it via reflection. Reflection is an api available in all languages.
Again don't know why u would be doing this but as the comments suggested
Get an better assignment -_-